# Apache Tiles 2.2.2 with FreeMarker views and prime faces 2 not working with el-api 2.2 in WAS 7

Tags: primefaces, freemarker, tiles2

We have primes faces which needs el-api 2.2 and also tiles 2.2.2 which seems to be using el-api 1.0 so tiles is not working. Below is the stack trace. It seems that tiles with el 2.2 is working in tomcat 7 but not in WAS 7. We are loading prime faces and el-api, el-impl2.2 using shared library with PARENT_LAST classloader.

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=freemarker/ext/jsp/FreeMarkerPageContext21, method=getELContext()Ljavax/el/ELContext;, pc=0
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:141)
    at freemarker.ext.jsp.PageContextFactory.<clinit>(PageContextFactory.java:26)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
```

Comment: please show the relevant code as well

Comment: Would you please elaborate on what code do u want me to add.

Comment: I'm not really a java guy, but ideally you should post a minimal code example which produces this exact trace.

Comment: Have you tried this on Sun/Oracle Java? Maybe it's an IBM J9-specific issue.

Comment: @stefan thanks for the help, as you can see in my stack trace this not generated from any of my code instead while loading/accessing the api classes. please see more details on the comment by mck.

Answer (score 0):

Even tiles-3 is built against el-api-1.0.

You can always try removing all old el-api and el-impl, ensuring only the 2.2 versions exist.
 …along the lines described here http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/HowToEnableEl22

If things still don't work you can file a [jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TILES) issue against tiles. It should at the minimum be on our todo list.

Comment: Thanks for the help. We are using WAS 7 and already tried the option of loading el-impl 2.2 but it's still not working.